# Editing the list of apps that appear when i share a file in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

On a Windows Store App project im using the [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871371.aspx) method to send a email with an attachment, and it is working well
but i would like to know if there is a way to define wich apps appear on the share list, for example i don't want the crossed apps to show.
just the first one.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. If you only want to send an e-mail you could call the e-mail app directly:

How to launch other apps https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452690.aspx

Mailto syntax http://www.labnol.org/internet/email/learn-mailto-syntax/6748/